# Has Azure exposed apis to enable the resources creation in azure portal?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

Has Azure exposed apis to enable the resources creation in azure portal?

I want to create a azure bot service through APIs from a different UI other than azure portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a azure bot service through APIs from a different UI other than azure portal.

It seems that you’d like to programmatically create BotService instead of creating it on Azure portal manually, if that is the case, you can try to use the following API:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/{deploymentName}?api-version=2018-02-01
```

For more information about this API, you can check the API documentation: [Deployments - Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/deployments/createorupdate).

Besides, [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager) provides resource group and resource management capabilities for Microsoft Azure, you can use this client library with ARM template and parameters to create BotService programmatically.

To quickly get template and sample code in .NET for deploying BotService, you can go Azure portal to create a new Bot Service and click **Automation options**, then you can **Download** the template and find the .NET code sample.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. While making the PUT request, what kind of authorization header need to be used? And how to create the access for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here is the Azure REST API Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/